# Search query parameter Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to adding and set parameters for query string with same key and different value  .

```
url.com/product.php?order=price.low&order=quantity.low
```

so there is a same key called order with different value.
i created some radio button for change product sort.
and add event listener like this :

```
  function lowQRadio() {
    document.getElementById("radio-qlow").checked=true;
    params.set("order","quantity.low");
    window.location.href=(location.pathname + '?' + params);

}
    function highQRadio() {
    document.getElementById("radio-qhigh").checked=true;
    params.set("order","quantity.high");
    window.location.href=(location.pathname + '?' + params);


}
    function  lowPRadio(){
    document.getElementById("radio-plow").checked=true;
    params.set("order","price.low");
    window.location.href=(location.pathname + '?' + params);
}
    function  highPRadio(){
    document.getElementById("radio-phigh").checked=true;
    params.set("order","price.high");
    window.location.href=(location.pathname + '?' + params);
}
```

some variable defined above this code and here is variables:

```
  let url = new URL(window.location.href);
    let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
    if(params.has("order")){
    var aflag=params.getAll("order");
    console.log(aflag.length);
    if(aflag[aflag.length-1]==="quantity.low" || aflag[aflag.length-2]==="quantity.low") {
    document.getElementById("radio-qlow").checked = true;
}
    else if(aflag[aflag.length-1]==="quantity.high" || aflag[aflag.length-2]==="quantity.high"){
    document.getElementById("radio-qhigh").checked=true;
}
    else if(aflag[aflag.length-1]==="price.low" || aflag[aflag.length-2]==="price.low"){
    document.getElementById("radio-plow").checked=true;
}
    else if(aflag[aflag.length-1]==="price.high" || aflag[aflag.length-2]==="price.high"){
    document.getElementById("radio-phigh").checked=true;
}
```

so i want when user choose sort by price and quantity ,both of this radio button will checked and query changed and if user choose one of sort method ,only one parameter set and if choose another one ,both of these checked and page will be refresh

the php code or back-end worked but js code work only for one type of radio button and both sort not  working!!

please help me to fix this,thanks with regards

Answer (score 0):

The query string is a name-value pair collection.  Names must be unique.  Do you want to do something like
url.html?OrderBy=col1,col2,col3

Use a delimited string as the query string parameter value, then in your php code split the value and use logic to apply the order by.

Comment: url.com?product.php?order=price.low&order=quantity.high , back-end works

Comment: Don't write something that fights against the way a query string is meant to work.